# How can I run example armadillo program

Tags: c++, g++, armadillo, fedora-23

I am trying to run the minimal [armadillo example program](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#example_prog) (bellow for convinience)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
  {
  mat A = randu<mat>(4,5);
  mat B = randu<mat>(4,5);
  cout << A*B.t() << endl; 
  return 0;
  }
```

I am running a linux fedora 23 distro and have the `armadillo` package installed.

```
$ sudo dnf list armadillo
Last metadata expiration check: 1:04:12 ago on Tue May 31 17:57:36 2016.
Installed Packages
armadillo.x86_64        6.700.6-1.fc23         @updates
Available Packages
armadillo.i686          6.700.6-1.fc23         updates
```

Though when I compiled the example program from the current directory I get:

```
$ g++ example.cpp -o example -O2 -larmadillo
example.cpp:2:21: fatal error: armadillo: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Fedora you also need to install the corresponding *development* package: armadillo-devel. This provides the header files required for compiling C++ programs that use armadillo.

For example:

```
sudo dnf install armadillo-devel
```